# Will long term high stress generally inhibit attraction or interests in new romances?

Tags: social-psychology, stress

Regarding the sort of long term stress that makes a person tense and unhappy on a daily basis for months, and how this affects that persons interest in new social connections.

I have read several articles about long term high stress causing trouble in existing romantic relationships, for various reasons.
Some people will also generally withdraw and seek isolation from other people, thus neglecting social bonding.

Will these stress periods generally also reduce/inhibit any interest in finding new romances?
Are hormones affecting attraction and bonding likely to get affected by stress?

I am looking for scientific research, papers, correlations, etc.

Comment: *"I have read several articles about long term high stress causing trouble in existing romantic relationships"* Can you please link to a couple of examples? This helps show what you have read to avoid duplication of what you already know.

Comment: The articles I have read were only about existing relationships, while my question is about new relationships. So those articles should not be relevant in an answer anyway.

Comment: Yesterday I found some vague, pseudoscientific articles that stress makes the body switch from producing sex hormones (or at least testosteron) to cortisol, which would indirectly reduce libido. Still looking for more scientific research and studies